# Different types of comparables

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

when implementing the comparator interface to achieve natural ordering of objects :

say if we had the class Account:

```
class Account
{
   Account(String name, int id) 
   int balance() 
   void deposit(int n)
}
```

we wanted to sort the Account balances of two accounts in order

**whats the diffrence between these two methods?**

```
public class comparebalances implements Comparable <Account>
{

     public int compare (Account acc1, Account acc2)
     {
       return acc1.balance()-acc2.balance();
     }

}

public class comparebalances implements Comparable <Account>
{

     public int compare (Account acc1, Account acc2)
     {
         if (acc1.balance()> acc2.balance())
            return 1;
         else if (acc1.balance()< acc2.balance())
            return -1;
         else if (acc1.balance()==acc2.balance())
            return 0;
     }

}
```

Comment: If you can guarantee that `balance()` is always >= 0, then the first approach is actually fine. If you can't, then you can end up beyond the negative range of `int`, and so you need to use the comparison operators as in the second example.

Comment: does this code even compile ( `int balance() `, no semi-colons,etc)?

Comment: nah, i wrote this example from the top of my head, have not been programming it.  Just trying to understand how it would work from my own examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one is safer, as the first one can provide wrong results for extreme values (integer overflow).

Answer (score 4):

As Puce already wrote, the second is safer where Integer overflow would give you unexpected output. If you want it short and safe at the same time, you can write:

```
return Integer.compare(acc1.balance(), acc2.balance());
```

Comment: Uh, nice, this is a new method since Java SE 7. Didn't know about that. Seems even to work on primitives not wrapper classes.